# Move directory to other directory preserving directory structure

Tags: files, find, mv, bash-functions

I want to move a file in `./dir1/subdir1` to `/dir2`, such that the end result is the existence of a directory `/dir2/dir1/subdir1` containing the files previously contained in `subdir1`.

I want to do this for all files found using a find command so it is important that the command takes input of the form `movecommand ./dir1/subdir1 /dir2/`, i.e. that I don't have to repeat the inner structure for the second argument.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

mv will copy the "last" object in your destination. In your case you can create the destination directory first, then move your files

```
mkdir /dir2/dir1/
mv /dir1/subdir/ /dir2/dir1/
```

or use rsync to copy and delete the source then

```
rsync -av dir1 dir2/
sending incremental file list
dir1/
dir1/subdir/
dir1/subdir/test1
dir1/subdir/test2

rm -r dir1
```